# continuous auto focus using intervalometer on a D700?

Tags: intervalometer

How do I set up continuous auto focus using intervalometer on a D700?

Comment: Can you describe what you're trying to shoot on an intervalometer that you want to use continuous autofocus?

Comment: Are you using the built-in intervalometer, or an external one?

Comment: AF-C?   Not sure of your meaning of continuous autofocus, but continuous focus only works when shutter is half pressed. Between intervals, the interval timer does not hold half press.  AF-C should work during full press of the timer.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to shoot several images with me and my birds... at a distance from the camera... using the intervalometer and an autofocus so I didn't have to keep disturbing the birds and getting up and walking to the camera, pressing the shutter release and have 10 seconds to get the birds looking cute and back to the chair. It's hard to do it one shot at a time.  But the first problem is the intervalometer is grayed out.